# React native iOS build failed Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, xcode15

I have developed a React Native project and attempted to execute the iOS build through Xcode. However, each attempt results in a failure with the error message "**Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code.**" What steps should I take to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?
**Project Configuration**
react-native:0.73.5
react: 18.2.0
node: 18.17.0

**Xcode version:** 15.3(15E204a)
**System Configuration:**
MacOS: Sonoma 14.2.1
Chip: M1
Memory: 8GB

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNFpa.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VY5L4.jpg)

To address this, I have already taken the following actions:

1. Deleted the pods and reinstalled them.
2. Cleaned the build and attempted to run the project again.
3. deleted derivedData files and tried to run again

Answer (score 0):

Delete this file fixed the issue: `ios\.xcode.env.local`

```
cd ios
rm -rf .xcode.env.local
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added any shell script to your scheme or in build phases?
It not, Have to tried to add OpenSSL to your project ?

In order to do so, go to your `target` and select `build phases`. then select `Link Binary With Libraries`, click on the plus sign and search for OpenSSL

[image]

Next do the following steps:

1. on the top nav click on `Product` and select `Clean Build Folder`.
2. Delete the derived data folder.
3. Delete Pods folder and Podfile.lock file.
4. Open xCode again and try to run it again.
5. Deleting xcode.env.local might hekp as well.

That helped me when initialize new react native project.
Hope that will help you as well.

Comment: tried the solution, but getting same issue again and again

Comment: Can you share entire log ?

Comment: sure. Attaching the link to view the log. https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/m45layq5qqm27y01ntd8k/Xcode_runtime_error.rtf?rlkey=1fibayqypkrkwijzj1pkmexkh&dl=0

Comment: Please run the command `pgrep oahd` and paste the output as new comment